# BigQuery table creation using Terraform - WriteDisposition

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform

I am creating a number of BigQuery datasets and tables using Terraform. I need to pass the bigquery.WriteDisposition parameter when creating a BQ table so that the table can be truncated or appended if it already exists. Otherwise, I will get an error 409 saying the table already exists and is a duplicate.

But, do you know if there is an option in Terraform to pass this parameter? I could not see any :-(

Answer (score 1):

According to the [terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/bigquery_job.html), there is `write_disposition` option. Possible values - `WRITE_TRUNCATE`, `WRITE_APPEND`, `WRITE_EMPTY`

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "foo" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.bar.dataset_id
  table_id   = "job_load_table"
}

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "bar" {
  dataset_id                  = "job_load_dataset"
  friendly_name               = "test"
  description                 = "This is a test description"
  location                    = "US"
}

resource "google_bigquery_job" "job" {
  job_id     = "job_load"

  labels = {
    "my_job" ="load"
  }

  load {
    source_uris = [
      "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states-by-date.csv",
    ]

    destination_table {
      project_id = google_bigquery_table.foo.project
      dataset_id = google_bigquery_table.foo.dataset_id
      table_id   = google_bigquery_table.foo.table_id
    }

    skip_leading_rows = 1
    schema_update_options = ["ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION", "ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION"]

    write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
    autodetect = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really. Here the write_disposition flag is added to a BigQuery Job resource, and not to the BigQuery Dataset/ Table resource.

Comment: Are you sure that Error 409 (duplication error) is caused by this?
If you change the value of `google_bigquery_job`'s `job_id`, will be the next run succeed? I'm asking this because the `google_bigquery_job` requires unique `job_id`s in each run, therefore something like this should be implemented here: `job_id="job_load_${uuid()}"`.